# Как переназначить cmd на Ctrl на Mac?

Tags: emacs

И в каком файле переназначить? Я создала файл `.emacs` в домашней директории. И у меня там написано:

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)
```

По идее <kbd>cmd</kbd> теперь должен быть равен <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Но у меня это не так. То ли файл не тот, то ли это для консольного emacs, а я пользуюсь приложением.

Всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, всё верно.

```
(setq mac-option-modifier 'meta)
```

Чтобы убедиться, можете выполнить эту команду через eval.
Тогда вы исключите ту причину, что файл по какой-то причине не читается.

Comment: Да вот я не знаю как эту команду выполнить через eval. Но мне не надо чтоб cmd было равно Alt, мне надо чтоб cmd было равно Ctrl, а я не знаю как. Но в любом случае, писать в этом файле - не вариант.

Comment: @КаришА: если ctrl, то и пишете соответственно ctrl. А как выполнить eval: M-: же

Comment: У меня нет файлов на компе - ни init.el, ни default.el, user.el. Но у меня есть в домашней директории .emacs.d - может надо что туда положить. А само приложение лежить в корне /Application/Emacs

Comment: @КаришА: создавайте там файлы спокойно и пишите там что нужно

Comment: Ок, спс. Напишу (setq mac-option-modifier 'ctrl). Теперь осталось понять куда писать.

Comment: @КаришА: в `~/emacs.d/init.el`

Comment: Не, создала в ~/.emacs.d/elpa файл init.el, написала, что нужно - не работает.

Comment: ~/emacs.d/user.el - тоже не работает

Comment: @КаришА: Во-первых, проверьте через eval, работает у вас вообще эта команда или нет, во-вторых, попробуйте её записать в `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (сорри, я пропустил точку в прошлый раз); так же вы можете с помощью C-x C-e выполнить буфер вручную (опять же для проверки)

Comment: Через eval проверила выводит 'meta - значит работает. Я не знаю что я такого сотворила, но теперь Cmd - это Alt.

Comment: @КаришА: Так вы же вроде бы изначально этого и хотели? Нет?

Comment: Нет :( я хотела назначить cmd на ctrl

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23375/discussion-between-igor-chubin-and-).

Comment: Вот так правильно:

Comment: (setq mac-command-modifier 'C)

Comment: Только щас печаль в том, чтобы это вступило в силу надо сделать execute C-x C-e

Comment: Пропишите в `~/.emacs.d/init.el`

Comment: Да он у меня, собственно, там и есть. Ето, видимо, надо куда-нибудь в /Application/Emacs/ положить

Comment: Нет, это будет неправильно, потому что у вас должны быть настройки на уровне пользователя, а не на уровне системы. Представьте, что у вас вообще нет доступа в `/Application/Emacs/`, ведь его могло бы и не быть. Все настройки должны лежать в `~/.emacs.d/`

Comment: ок, тогда не буду. Да, в принципе, зайти раз в день и напечатать M-x eval-buffer не особо напряжно

Comment: Да это неправиль, КаришА! Надо добить проблему, потмоу что так работать невозможно

Comment: Да фиг с ним. Этот вопрос решен, а как сделать настройки глобальными - это уже другой вопрос.